# Grails MongoDB Update object with Association

Tags: mongodb, grails

I can't seem to understand where I am going wrong currently when I attempt to update my User domain model that has a hasOne association to a Profile object.

My domain models are as follows:

```
class User {

    static hasOne = [profile: Profile]
    static fetchMode = [profile: 'eager']

    ObjectId id
    String username
}

class Profile {
   static belongsTo = [user: User]
   ObjectId id
   String familyName
   String givenName
}
```

I am able to persist a User with a profile originally but when attempting to update the User object I get validation errors.

```
Validation error occurred during call to save():
- Field error in object 'co.suitable.User' on field 'profile.familyName': rejected value [null]
- Field error in object 'co.suitable.User' on field 'profile.givenName': rejected value [null]
```

I am able to print out the user.profile ID and also the user.profile.familyName before saving the object. Like the following:

```
println(user.profile.familyName)
println(user.profile.id.toString())
user.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
```

But I still get the validation errors before saving, i'd imagine that the `println(user.profile.familyName)` call is fetching the profile object if it already hasn't been loaded which I thought setting the fetchMode would have handled.

The object is able to successfully persist and save when I do:

```
user.profile = Profile.findById(user.profile.id)
println(user.profile.id.toString())
user.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
```

I could wrap that in a service but I was hoping for a solution that would be handled by Grails if possible. Any advice or thoughts is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not apply the logic for the SQL DB to Mongo 1 to 1. Mongo and other document-oriented DBs are not originally intended to store the joins between collections. There are some workarounds, like `db-refs`, but they are to be used with caution.

For your case - with `hasOne` - I would suggest using mongo's `subdocuments` (mirrored as GORM's `embedded` objects) instead of referencing:

```
class User {

    ObjectId id
    String username

    Profile profile
    static embedded = [ 'profile' ]

}

class Profile {
   String familyName
   String givenName
}
```

thus you use the mongo in accordance to it's original puprose. Also querying is simpler and faster.

Comment: I agree that I should stray away from traditional SQL constructs so your answer does provide a nice solution but I was also hoping to get some light shed on why Grails is able to auto fetch the properties in the User to Profile association but when time comes to persist they seem to be missing? This is seen in the println() before my Save() call.